# change choose file text by file name in jsp filefield

Tags: html, jsp

I have file field to upload a file (pdf) in page demo.jsp, now i want when user going to edit this page say demo.jsp , previously uploaded file name will populate in file field in place of "Choose file".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this ( *work around*)

```
<input type="text" id="fileName" readonly="readonly" >
</br>
<small>Here change this with whatever dynamically</small>
</br>
<div class="file_input_div" style="display: inline;">
<input type="button" id="button" value="Open"/>
<input type="file"  style="opacity:0; position:relative; left:-40px;"  onchange="javascript: document.getElementById ('fileName').value = this.value"/>
</div>
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/codingantGit/hrYn2/358/)</kbd>

**Edit 2**

```
<small id='fileName'>Here change this with whatever dynamically</small>
</br>
<div class="file_input_div" style="display: inline;">
<input type="button" id="button" value="Open"/>
<input type="file"  style="opacity:0; position:relative; left:-40px;"  onchange="javascript: document.getElementById('fileName').innerHTML = this.value"/>
</div>
```

[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/hrYn2/361/)

Comment: Actually i want my uploaded file name show in file field so that if user not select new file when he edit other field and leave file field untouched then file field (choose file) should not required,and old, populated file name is update in table.